# Logstash to Elasticsearch Bulk Request , SSL peer shut down incorrectly- Manticore::ClientProtocolException logstash

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

ES version - 2.3.5 , Logstash - 2.4

'Attempted to send bulk request to Elasticsearch, configured at ["xxxx.com:9200"] ,
An error occurred and it failed! Are you sure you can reach elasticsearch from this machine using the configuration provided ?

Error:

> "SSL peer shut down incorrectly", Manticore::ClientProtocolException
>   logstash"'

My logstash Output section:

```
output
{
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
stdout { codec => json }
elasticsearch
{
user => "xxxx"
password => "xxx"
index => "wrike_jan"
document_type => "data"
hosts => ["xxxx.com:9200"]
ssl => true
ssl_certificate_verification => false
truststore => "elasticsearch-2.3.5/config/truststore.jks"
truststore_password => "83dfcdddxxxxx"
}
}
```

Logstash file is executed , but it is failing to send the data to ES.

Could you please suggest, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be particular about http or https in the url, in the above case i am sending data to https but my ES is using http.
Later, upgrade of logstash version solved to send data to ES.